# Validating python regex flags specified in json

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a tool which accepts user configuration via a json file. One piece of this config is a python regular expression and some optional regex flags. Currently the configuration for the regex flags is an array of integers which will all be run through a bitwise or (|) and sent to the re compile method.

My question is how can I validate these integers to ensure that they are valid re flags?

EDIT: Or potentially another solution to my problem... Is it possible for the user to specify the actual re flags in the JSON? I.e., [re.DEBUG, re.IGNORECASE] etc etc and then somehow translate those from the JSON file in my python script?

Comment: Is it for Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ideally I would like both to be supported

Comment: It seems you may use `if option in [2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256]` to validate these. Just note that `re.ASCII` (256) is only present in Python 3 `re`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what about my edit? Do you think its possible to allow the user to specify the name of the flag instead? That would be a lot more descriptive and helpful

Comment: Then you may create a dictionary and map the names with the real flags, i.e. `option_dct = { 're.I' : re.I, etc. }`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If you make an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a dictionary of all possible flags (they are really few, see `re`  [*6.2.2. Module Contents*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-contents)), and just get the value by the corresponding key.

A [Python demo](https://ideone.com/7G8DXD):

```
import re
re_flags = { 're.A' : re.A, 
    're.ASCII' : re.ASCII,
    're.DEBUG' : re.DEBUG,
    're.I' : re.I,
    're.IGNORECASE' : re.IGNORECASE,
    're.L' : re.L,
    're.LOCALE' : re.LOCALE,
    're.M' : re.M,
    're.MULTILINE' : re.MULTILINE,
    're.S' : re.S,
    're.DOTALL' : re.DOTALL,
    're.X' : re.X,
    're.VERBOSE' : re.VERBOSE }
flg = 're.I'                      # User input
if flg in re_flags:               # If the dict contains the key
    print(re_flags[flg])          # Print the value (re.I = 2)
```

If you still want to go with numbers instead:

```
import re
print(re.A)           # 256
print(re.ASCII)       # 256
print(re.DEBUG)       # 128
print(re.I)           # 2
print(re.IGNORECASE)  # 2
print(re.L)           # 4
print(re.LOCALE)      # 4
print(re.M)           # 8
print(re.MULTILINE)   # 8
print(re.S)           # 16
print(re.DOTALL)      # 16
print(re.X)           # 64
print(re.VERBOSE)     # 64
```

Comment: Yeah I assigned them to the raw numbers because i don't know whether my script will be being run in python 2 or 3 so if I try to use the re module there are some flags which do not exist in python 2 etc